# Need help with displaying text depending on choice

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, isblank

I am trying to get this formula to work.

I want: IF column `ärende tilldelat` is blank I want the calculated column to say "Ej tilldelad".

If you have chosen "Tillkoppling" in the column `Ärendetyp` I want it to say "test".

```
 =IF(ISBLANK(OR([Ärende tilldelat]);"Ej tilldelad";([Ärendetyp="Tillkoppling";"test";TEXT([Ärende tilldelat]-[Ärende inkommet];"hh:mm:ss")))
```

IF "Ärende tilldelad" ISBLANK display "Ej tilldelad" in the calculated column

Else IF choosen "Tillkoppling" in column "Ärendetyp" display "Test" in the calculated column.

Comment: What is the data type of `ärende tilldelat` and `Ärendetyp` columns? are you getting any error using above formula?

Comment: I get syntax error. "Ärende tilldelat" is a plain text column and "ärendetyp" is a dropdown choice column

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding your requirements are (correct me if I am wrong):

```
IF [Ärende tilldelat] is blank then calculated column = "Ej tilldelad"
Else IF [Ärendetyp]="Tillkoppling" then calculated column = "test"
Else calculated column = difference between [Ärende tilldelat] and [Ärende inkommet] in format of "hh:mm:ss".
```

Try using below formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Ärende tilldelat]);"Ej tilldelad";IF([Ärendetyp]="Tillkoppling";"test";TEXT([Ärende tilldelat]-[Ärende inkommet];"hh:mm:ss")))
```

Comment: This kinda worked. It still says "Ej tilldelad" If I have choosen "Tillkoppling" but when i put in a value in "Ärende inkommet" is says "Test". I would like it to know directly if it should say "Ej tilldelad" or "test".

Comment: Please add all the possible conditions you want to cover in your question. It will be easier to answer your question.

Comment: Sorry if i'm giving you a hard time. I've edited my question

Comment: What is the 3rd possibility? If `[Ärende tilldelat]` is not blank and `[Ärendetyp]` is not equal to "Tillkoppling" then what should be the value of your calculated column??

Comment: It should just be the value [Ärende tilldelat] - [Ärende inkommet] it shows "hh:mm:ss"

Comment: What is the datatype of `[Ärende inkommet]`? Do you want the value in `hh:mm:ss` format or not??

Comment: [Ärende inkommet] is just plain text ex. "2012-01-24 09:11:23" and in the calculated column I want to format hh:mm:ss

Comment: Either You need to use date and time columns or you need to convert them into Date in calculated column formulas. Check date functions at: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14).

Comment: Hi, have you managed to get it working?

Comment: No, sorry. I'm kinda stuck and I dont know what to do.